# The best way to backup and restore a Linux Mail Server?

Tags: linux, backup, email

I have a Linux Postfix mail server, and I am doing a configuration backup via FTP. but actually thinking about it, this will give me a 3-4 day period for recover my server...
whats is the best way to recover my server in case of failure (hours instead of days)?
thanks...

Answer (score 3):

1. Use automated machine build tools (Kickstart, Debian Installer Preseeding) to make machines quick and easy to create
2. Use configuration management to maintain the configuration of the server so it's easy to reapply the configuration
3. Regularly test that the backups you take are useful by running an entire restore from bare metal.

Answer (score 1):

in addition to womble's suggestion, tar zcvf + ssh is your friend on a linux server. Once you have a server's configuration where you want it, simply

```
tar zcvf - directory_to_backup/ | ssh someotherserver "cat > serverbackupfile.tgz"
```

to save a copy of the important configurations.